# Sencha touch template append tutorial

Tags: templates, sencha-touch, store

My list looks like this :

```
var list = new Ext.List({
   fullscreen: true,    
   itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',   
   store: store
});
```

and model and store like this:

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
   fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      model  : 'Contact',
   },
   data: [
      {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
      {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
      {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},

  ]
});
```

How would I append to my itemTpl in my list or overwrite it after it has been initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Edited to reflect the question ***

This will do the trick i guess:

```
list.itemTpl = '{firstName} {lastName} Test Test Test';
list.initComponent();
list.refresh();
```

When you are using Sencha Touch 2 ( tested it in my app )

```
list.setItemTpl( '{firstName} {lastName} Test Test Test' );
list.refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to change the itemTpl though, I edited the question to reflect this.